# Append rows just beneath an excel using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

First data frame is:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

Second data frame is:

| a1 | b | c1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |

What I expect is:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |

Just move all values from df2 in df1, the column names may be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to concatenate the underlying numpy arrays and build a DataFrame:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(np.r_[df1.to_numpy(), df2.to_numpy()], columns=df1.columns)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

Answer (score 1):

Create same columns names in both DataFrames and use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df2.columns = df1.columns

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Or:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2.rename(columns=dict(zip(df2.columns, df1.columns)))])
```